# Apollo grapgql error on image upload on node 14

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

According to the Apollo graphql site as they mentioned,

> Apollo Server's built-in support for file uploads relies on an old version of the graphql-upload npm package for backward compatibility. This old version is not fully compatible with Node 14.

due to that reason, I disable built-in support by passing uploads: false to the ApolloServer constructor. You can then install and use the lastest version of graphql-upload directly as follow,

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: gql`
  
    scalar Upload
  
    // here other typedefs
  `,
  resolvers: {
    Upload: GraphQLUpload,
    Query: {
      hello: () => "Hey!"
    },
    Mutation: {

      singleUpload: s3Uploader.singleFileUploadResolver.bind(s3Uploader),
      multipleUpload: s3Uploader.multipleUploadsResolver.bind(s3Uploader)
    }
  },
  uploads:false,
});
```

but in that case I got following error when try to upload image as in the below image
[image]
when it inspect through network that there is a response as above which is,

> POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?

I tried many ways to solve this issue and you can follow following link to get full code base [code base](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-sunset-uki24)

**If remove upload: false and scalar type from apollo constructor and try to run it will only work for node 12 not for node 14**

Comment: so where to add my middleware

Comment: rest of the doc dosen't include solution for this